# Windows new postgresql installation refusing every password

Tags: powershell, passwords, postgresql

so I just installed Postgresql, sewt up PATH to use it with Powershell and  entered my first psql command.

The response: "Password for user *(my WINDOWS username).

NO password works. Not the one for the "postgres" user I set up in the installer, not my windows account password, not leaving it empty, nothing.

So where does this password come from and what is it?
I googled default passwords, I tried some default-sounding ones, to no avail.

It also might be that this is helpful BUT the selected answer uses menues that do not exist in 2020 [Default password for postgreSQL](https://superuser.com/questions/576623/default-password-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the answer is that Postgresql is just VERY VERY unintuitive!

Because the default account it tries to log in as DOES NOT EVEN EXIST!

**what you need to to is use "psql -U postgres"** instead

This ensures that you log in as the user "postgres", where the password you used in the installer will work.